# PHP: include path and running script from windows cmd

Tags: php

Lets say I have a such folder structure:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject
                    |-- Lib
                    |    |-- dbconn.php
                    |-- SuperSite
                    |    |-- index.php
                    |    |-- misc
                    |          |-- misc.php
```

index.php has a such line:

```
require("../Lib/dbconn.php");
```

This will work if you access index.php from web server, but require() will fail if you will run index.php from the command line:

```
C:\>php C:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject\SuperSite\index.php
Warning: include(../Lib/dbconn.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject\SuperSite\index.php
```

However, it will not fail if I add "/" in front of the path:

```
require("/../Lib/dbconn.php");
```

Nor it will fail if I require other file like this:

```
require("misc/misc.php");
```

or

```
require("/misc/misc.php");
```

Why does having "/" in front of the path that starts with ".." is required when running script from command line?

(Paths with or without "/" in front works if accessing from web server (using browser))

Comment: I believe it is a good idea to access all your pages from a file at the root, this way you will always know in which folder you are in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this page will help you ! ;)

[Path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29)